# Missing properties when deserializing JSON in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, deserialization

I'm trying to deserialize this data from an API, but I'm some properties gets null value, there is a json:

```
"statistics": {
                    "Shots on Goal": {
                        "home": "1",
                        "away": "2"
                    },
                    "Shots off Goal": {
                        "home": "6",
                        "away": "5"
                    },
                    "Total Shots": {
                        "home": "9",
                        "away": "8"
                    },
                    "Blocked Shots": {
                        "home": "2",
                        "away": "1"
                    },
                    "Shots insidebox": {
                        "home": "6",
                        "away": "7"
                    },
                    "Shots outsidebox": {
                        "home": "3",
                        "away": "1"
                    },
                    "Fouls": {
                        "home": "5",
                        "away": "3"
                    },
                    "Corner Kicks": {
                        "home": "3",
                        "away": "4"
                    },
                    "Offsides": {
                        "home": "3",
                        "away": "0"
                    },
                    "Ball Possession": {
                        "home": "62%",
                        "away": "38%"
                    },
                    "Yellow Cards": {
                        "home": null,
                        "away": null
                    },
                    "Red Cards": {
                        "home": null,
                        "away": null
                    },
                    "Goalkeeper Saves": {
                        "home": "1",
                        "away": "1"
                    },
                    "Total passes": {
                        "home": "394",
                        "away": "220"
                    },
                    "Passes accurate": {
                        "home": "330",
                        "away": "158"
                    },
                    "Passes %": {
                        "home": "84%",
                        "away": "72%"
                    }
                }
```

This is my mapping class:
in a parent class

```
[JsonProperty("statistics")]
public Statistics statistics { get; set; }
```

and

```
public class Statistics
        {
            [JsonProperty("Shots on Goal")]
            public ShotsonGoal ShotsonGoal { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Shots off Goal")]
            public ShotsoffGoal ShotsoffGoal { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Total Shots")]
            public TotalShots TotalShots { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Blocked Shots")]
            public BlockedShots BlockedShots { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Shots insidebox")]
            public Shotsinsidebox Shotsinsidebox { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Shots outsidebox")]
            public Shotsoutsidebox Shotsoutsidebox { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Fouls")]
            public Fouls Fouls { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Corner Kicks")]
            public CornerKicks CornerKicks { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Offsides")]
            public Offsides Offsides { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Ball Possession")]
            public BallPossession BallPossession { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Yellow Cards")]
            public YellowCards YellowCards { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Red Cards")]
            public RedCards RedCards { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Goalkeeper Saves")]
            public GoalkeeperSaves GoalkeeperSaves { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Total passes")]
            public Totalpasses Totalpasses { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Passes accurate")]
            public Passesaccurate Passesaccurate { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("Passes %")]
            public Passes Passes { get; set; }
        }

        public class ShotsonGoal
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class ShotsoffGoal
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class TotalShots
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class BlockedShots
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class Shotsinsidebox
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class Shotsoutsidebox
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class Fouls
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class CornerKicks
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class Offsides
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class BallPossession
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class YellowCards
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class RedCards
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class GoalkeeperSaves
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class Totalpasses
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class Passesaccurate
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }

        public class Passes
        {
            public string home { get; set; }
            public string away { get; set; }
        }
```

This is what I'm getting:
[image]

Some properties are missing.

These properties have values but my deserializer seems to skip them.

Any help will be very helpful.

Comment: What code are you using to parse the Json? Your example Json value is missing opening and closing braces.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sooDVe. Most likely it's because you're trying to parse the whole thing as a `Statistics` rather than one of the properties. Posting the real Json string you're parsing will answer that.

Comment: Show how you are parsing the json text. Also you don't need to create so many classes, you can reuse one class for all those properties of statistics because everything has same home and away fields only.

Comment: Yes it's missing brackets because it's a long Json and I only posted what is interested here.
the code to parse the json is:  var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<LiveFixtures>(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
Where LiveFixtures is a list of fixtures and a fixture contains a statistics property

Answer (score 1):

Cannot see much wrong with that, but to make things simpler (and potentially eliminate the issue) you could use a common class for each property like so -

```
public class Statistics
{
    [JsonProperty("Shots on Goal")]
    public HomeAwayStats ShotsonGoal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Shots off Goal")]
    public HomeAwayStats ShotsoffGoal { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Total Shots")]
    public HomeAwayStats TotalShots { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Blocked Shots")]
    public HomeAwayStats BlockedShots { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Shots insidebox")]
    public HomeAwayStats Shotsinsidebox { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Shots outsidebox")]
    public HomeAwayStats Shotsoutsidebox { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Fouls")]
    public HomeAwayStats Fouls { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Corner Kicks")]
    public HomeAwayStats CornerKicks { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Offsides")]
    public HomeAwayStats Offsides { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Ball Possession")]
    public HomeAwayStats BallPossession { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Yellow Cards")]
    public HomeAwayStats YellowCards { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Red Cards")]
    public HomeAwayStats RedCards { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Goalkeeper Saves")]
    public HomeAwayStats GoalkeeperSaves { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Total passes")]
    public HomeAwayStats Totalpasses { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Passes accurate")]
    public HomeAwayStats Passesaccurate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Passes %")]
    public HomeAwayStats Passes { get; set; }
}

public class HomeAwayStats
{
    public string home { get; set; }
    public string away { get; set; }
}
```

That would simplify your code a lot more and reduce the potential for typos in the copied classes/properties further down the line.

Is the JSON that you have posted the actual JSON that is producing the result in the screen shot?

Comment: Thanks indeed it would be much simpler. I changed it like this but this is not eliminating the issue. Yes the JSON you see is part of what I get from the API, I pasted only what is interested here.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the '%' character in 'Passes %' might be causing an issue, I wonder if in needs to be encoded in the JsonProperty attribute?

Comment: Just tested with/without the '%' encoding and can confirm it is not the issue - is there a way you can paste the complete JSON and the full hierarchy of classes (you mention in a comment above the top level class is LiveFixtures) so the whole thing can be run in dotnetfiddle?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it work by changing the way I'm parsing the json from:

```
var response = await client.ExecuteAsync<LiveFixtures>(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
```

to:

```
var myJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LiveFixtures>(response.Content);
```

Thanks for taking time to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered this issue myself.
Basically it comes down to making sure the object you are deserializing to has the EXACT fields that are specified in the payload.

TL;DR: C# WebAPI can return objects with wrong properties capitalization and break JsonSerializer.

For example, my object had `BFG` and `UAE_Directorate` as two of my object properties.
When I did

```
await JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<List<Doom>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
```

I found that the `BFG` and `UAE_Directorate` properties were missing from each of my Doom entries.

I troubleshooted by just reading it to string instead and seeing where the problem was:

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync());
Debug.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
```

found that the property `BFG` was being returned as lowercased `bfg` and `UAE_Directorate` was returned as `uaE_Directorate`. Therefore, the JsonSerializer could not deserialize those fields and just left them as null.

You must correct it on the receiving end by changing the capitalization to fit what was returned.